# Is ostream_iterator efficient?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I just learned how to use `ostream_iterator` today, but I don't know if this is efficient comparing to the normal for-loop way.

Here is the code:

```
//The first one
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ostream_iterator<int> osit(cout, " ");
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), osit);
```

And

```
//The second one
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int i : v) cout << i << " ";
```

Which one is more efficient?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using stream is inefficient most of the times, especially when you interact with the underlying system (`cout` / `cin` / `fstream` / ...), so you won't see a difference between both ways since the "efficiency" of the methods will be hidden by the inefficiency of the stream.

Comment: The ranged-based for loop requires slightly less typing.

Comment: Define "efficient".   By some measures (like number of characters typed) the second may be more efficient.   By others (e.g. ability to use the same `ostream_iterator` more than once, to output multiple vectors of int) the first may be.   If your measure is cpu cycles or memory usage, then the results depend on quality of the compiler and coding of the standard library.   So, the real answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::copy` is using `operator=` from the iterator. It looks something like this

```
ostream_iterator& operator=(const _Ty& _Val)
{   // insert value into output stream, followed by delimiter
    *_Myostr << _Val;
    if (_Mydelim != 0)
    {
        *_Myostr << _Mydelim;
    }

    return (*this);
}
```

Looks very similar to the code you have in your for-loop, except for the conditional output of the separator (which takes zero time compared to formatting the integer and outputting it).